# How to publish Android library without sharing source code?

Tags: android, maven, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

I want my clients to be able to import my Android library **without the possibility for them to have access to the source code of that library**.

I want also for them to be able to easily import that library using gradle :

```
compile "my.group.package:thelibrary:1.0.0"
```

The problem is that using any method such as Jitpack/Jcenter/MavenCentral will make the source code available via the GitHub repository! (am I wrong here?)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please look into this answer for obfuscating your library for redistribution :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17907492/1552960

Comment: So I'm confused here. Let's say I'm using jitpack to share my library with my client. Even if my library is obfuscated, the entire source code will be available by accessing the repository on githud. Correct ?

Comment: If you post the library after it has been obsfucated then it should be fine, do you understand what obsfucation is? :)