# Publish android library with private source code (Free)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-library

I am working on the development of an android library with confidential APIs. I want to publish the library and make it publicly accessible but cannot open-source the code.

Is there any software or a way to publish the library while keeping the code private?

I can use jitpack with private repo but that is paid.
Is there any alternative / free solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the solutions you're looking for is **obfuscating**. see this related question:
[android library project obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873147/android-library-project-obfuscation)

and also here: [Setting up ProGuard with Android Library Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166380/setting-up-proguard-with-android-library-projects/44416243)

---

when you obfuscate your code it is still open to be read by others, but it changes some way that is not readable by human.

Comment: I didn't get it. Even if I obfuscate, how do I distribute my library? The clients should be able to add my library in their app as a dependency.

Comment: it is possible for others to add it. the only thing about that is they cannot read your code and change it. notice that there will be no problem for intellisense.

and for publishing I suggest you to publish that in github

Comment: https://sgkantamani.medium.com/how-to-create-and-publish-an-android-library-f37bf715932 - https://proandroiddev.com/publishing-android-libraries-to-the-github-package-registry-part-1-7997be54ea5a

for more info

Comment: or you can publish it on maven - https://medium.com/@zubairehman.work/a-complete-guide-to-create-and-publish-an-android-library-to-maven-central-6eef186a42f5 for more info

Comment: Thank you. After obfuscation, can I use jitpack and upload my code to github ?

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is that this is not possible. You cannot publish plain text code that is private. By definition publishing means it is not private.
Obfuscated code is reasonably easy to reverse engineer, although the logic may be harder to follow without method/variable names.

In particular, API key strings will not be obfuscated at all by proguard. You have to live with the fact that your API keys are in the public domain as soon as you publish them.